# Any idea to make this code better with array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a update function that get a input from user and replace old input with new input:

```php
    /**
     * Update input values in $detail
     *
     * @param array $detail :validated input event data
     */
    public static function updateUserInput(array $detail)
    {
        $event              = self::find($detail['id']);
        $event->your_name   = $detail['your_name'];
        $event->email       = $detail['email'];
        $event->title       = $detail['title'];
        $event->location    = $detail['location'];
        $event->description = $detail['description'];
        $event->date        = $detail['date'];
        $event->save();
    }
```

But it has many iteration like `$event->foo` and `$detal['bar'];`.
How would you deal with this code to make it nice and clear?

Comment: use [`laravel` mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment), something like `$event->fill($detail)`. do remember that it needs the properties having the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the array keys are the same as the model attributes

you can loop through the attributes list of the model and assign accordingly

```php
public static function updateUserInput(array $detail)
{
  $event = self::find($detail['id']);
  foreach(array_keys($event->getAttributes()) as $attribute) {
    $event->$attribute = $detail[$attribute];
  }
  $event->save();
}
```

Or use the Eloquent `fill()` method and pass it the array of data as pointed out in the comments

```php
public static function updateUserInput(array $detail)
{
  $event = self::find($detail['id']);
  $event->fill($detail);
  $event->save();
}
```

But you would have to add all attributes to the protected `$fillable` property in the model or set `$guarded` to an empty array
`Event.php`

```php
protected $guarded = [];
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Just hit it

```
self::findOrFail($data['id'])->update($data);
```

Make sure your fillable in your model According to your $data parameter index identifier

Comment: thank you for your answer. Btw, what do I need to google to study your suggestion?(I googled some of your keywords but not so sure)

Comment: @JunoJ you may try , How to save array data in one Statement for Laravel. Actually Laravel made this more easy to save your data with in a line through array's object. If you define all table column name in your model through -- protected $fillable = ['col1','col2','col3'] and put the same name in input field what u write inside form tag. whenever col1 has any data and u use model for data insertion it will be find column name according to input field name and insert inside this column according to your fillable.